# mainActivity.runOnUiThread Updates data in a table too slowly

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency

I have a producer thread that feeds data to a consumer, if i print this data to logcat, it works wonderfully and fast. As soon as I try to update my table in the ui using runOnUiThread, some of the data will display, wait an arbitrary amount of time and then keep updating until it s done. Instead of a second this process can take minutes.

```
public class DeviceFragment extends Fragment {
static Boolean loop = true;
static Object lock = new Object();
static SnmpPdu pdu;

//handlers initialized in onCreate

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final SnmpWalk snmpWalk = new SnmpWalk(ipAddress, PDUs, lock);
        looperThreadProducerHandler.post(snmpWalk);
        looperThreadConsumerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        while (snmpWalk.getWalkStart()) {
                            synchronized(PDUs) {
                                if (PDUs.size() != 0) {
                                    pdu = PDUs.remove(0);
                                    Log.d("test", "" + pdu.toString());//this will print fine if i don't call the doWork method
                                    try {
                                        doWork(pdu); //display to ui
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    public void doWork(SnmpPdu pdu) throws InterruptedException {
                        final TableLayout deviceTable = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.deviceTable);
                        final TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
                        //skip row initalizers here
                        loop = false;
                        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                deviceTable.addView(row);
                                synchronized(lock) {
                                    loop = true;
                                    lock.notify();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                        synchronized(lock) {
                            while (!loop) {
                                lock.wait();
                            }
                        }
                    }
         }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have synchronized blocks for "lock"? What are you requiring to be thread safe?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify() Therefore i need to synchronize the locks, I need the data to be in order. So i am trying to achieve a sequential execution.

Comment: If you remove the sync, the notify and the wait, and have a while loop that gets deactivated after your view is added, you should have a sequential order?

Comment: Also, try to find where your doWork method is spending most of its time. Put in some Logs to determine how much time is being spent at various code blocks.

Comment: having a blocking while loop in the main thread is bad practice. Although i got rid of all the synchronized blocks and data comes in order. I guess being too paranoid on being thread safe can fire back. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem. Your issue was due to the two synchronized blocks working on the same lock at the same time. It will first lock outside the Runnable, then attempt to lock again inside the Runnable. Incidentally, if doWork is running on your main thread, why do you have runOnUiThread at all? That is not necessary in that case.

Comment: in android isn t the ui thread the main thread?

Comment: Yes. However, you stated "having a blocking while loop in the main thread is bad practice". Your previous code had the same loop. So I am wondering if your "looperThreadConsumerHandler" is running in the main thread. If it is, then having a loop there is probably a bad idea. In that case, you can remove the loop AND remove the call to runOnUiThread.

Comment: consumer and producer threads are separate from the main thread. The producer can actually take a long time. There may be tens of thousands of pdus produced. Not exactly sure how i could have the main thread accept all the pdus from producer and not block the ui.

Comment: OK, in this case, there is no issue having the while loop, and I don't understand why you wrote "having a blocking while loop in the main thread is bad practice". As neither your old or new code should have that.

Comment: ahh it s alright, no worries. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: No problem. I'll make an answer so this question can be finalized.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is due to the two `synchronized` blocks working on the same lock at the same time. It will first lock outside the `Runnable`, then attempt to lock again inside the `Runnable`.

```
synchronized(lock) {
    loop = true;
    lock.notify();
}
```

And

```
synchronized(lock) {
    while (!loop) {
        lock.wait();
    }
}
```

This can comfortably be converted to:

```
loop = true;
```

And

```
while (!loop) { }
```